# nutch 1.10 job failed, bad request error indexing to solr 5.3.1

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

I have put together a crawler in a test environment that was running just fine with 2 small sites, including successfully indexing to solr. So, the integration between nutch and solr seem to be fine.

The only change I have made is adding another site to seed.txt and another line in regex-urlfilters.txt, using the exact same syntax as the other sites.

Now when I run the crawler it runs fine for a while then crashes with a 'Job failed!' error and little helpful information.

This is the output to console. It is useful to note that this is the 3rd segment created in the crawl so it has already successfully indexed 2 segments before the error. Could there be something in the new site that is causing corruption?

```
Indexing 20151030150906 to index
/opt/apache-nutch-1.10/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCrawlCore TestCrawl//crawldb -linkdb TestCrawl//linkdb TestCrawl//segments/20151030150906
Indexer: starting at 2015-10-30 15:14:00
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
    solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
    solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth.username : username for authentication
    solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:113)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:187)

Error running:
  /opt/apache-nutch-1.10/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCrawlCore TestCrawl//crawldb -linkdb TestCrawl//linkdb TestCrawl//segments/20151030150906
Failed with exit value 255.
```

This is the relevant data from hadoop.log

```
2015-10-30 15:14:00,854 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: starting at 2015-10-30 15:14:00
2015-10-30 15:14:00,909 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
2015-10-30 15:14:00,909 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: URL filtering: false
2015-10-30 15:14:00,910 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: URL normalizing: false
2015-10-30 15:14:01,113 INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
2015-10-30 15:14:01,113 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication


2015-10-30 15:14:01,118 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: crawldb: TestCrawl/crawldb
2015-10-30 15:14:01,118 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: linkdb: TestCrawl/linkdb
2015-10-30 15:14:01,119 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: TestCrawl/segments/20151030150906
2015-10-30 15:14:01,264 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-10-30 15:14:01,722 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off
2015-10-30 15:14:02,253 INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2015-10-30 15:14:02,271 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2015-10-30 15:14:02,370 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 38 documents
2015-10-30 15:14:02,487 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 38 documents
2015-10-30 15:14:02,524 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local593696138_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCrawlCore/update?wt=javabin&version=2
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:153)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:115)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:535)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)
2015-10-30 15:14:03,508 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:113)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:187)
```

I'm just figuring this stuff out so I don't know the next step in troubleshooting this problem. Any help would be appreciated. I'm happy to include more information if there is something specific that would be helpful.

Comment: Is there anything in the Solr logs?

Comment: Ah. Excellent question. The Solr log has some undefined field: "anchor" errors in it. That sounds like maybe a schema problem? Sams schema that is working for the other two sites.

Comment: I would guess a schema problem but would need to see the logs to say anything definitive or otherwise troubleshoot further.

Comment: I think I might have found it. There was an "anchor" field in the nutch schema that I didn't have in the Solr schema. I'll know in a minute if it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Solr schemas can be a bit tricky and annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a mismatch between the nutch and solr schemas.

Thanks to TMBT (see comments above) I found an additional error in the Solr logs claiming "unidentified field: "anchor".

All I had to do was copy the anchor field declaration from the nutch schema into the Solr schema and restart the solr service. Now running fine.

Comment: I'm still having this problem even though I've copied the `schema.xml` from my Nutch 1.12 to my solr 4.3's `example/solr/collection1/conf` folder... very annoying this error...

Comment: First thing I would try is a newer version of solr

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear where the development of Solr and Nutch are going. Only a few versions are known to be compatible with each other. I decided to choose Nutch 2.3.1 and Solr 4.10.3, as suggested here: https://nutch.apache.org/ and I still had a lot of problems. I've never faced so many problems because of the fault of the creators.